# Swift - private var/func vs. private final var/func

Tags: swift, private, final

I am aware that by making properties and methods final in Swift, I can improve both compile time and app's performance. Recently I read Apple blog post: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27, which states that making property or method (file)private (blog post dates back to 2015 when "private" meant "fileprivate") enables the compiler to infer "finality" of property or method, by searching the source file for any overrides. But what about "real" (Swift 3) private? The compiler shouldn't have to search anywhere for potential overrides, so my question is: 
 Is there any performance and/or compilation time difference between these two declarations?

```
private final var foo: Int

private var bar: Int
```

Comment: In the first one you can not change the value once assigned and is only accessible within that class.In second one you can change value and that also only accessible in same class.

Comment: Sorry, my question might not have been specific enough. I what these two declarations do (moreover your statement is incorrect: you CAN assign new value to final var - it's not Java). I'm wondering if there is any performance difference between them.

Comment: No there is no performance issue.

Answer (score 4):

Method or property marked as `private` is implicitly `final`. 
In tests that are provided from @conarch is one side effect - Dispatching class.

I make the same test as fallow:

```
    class UseFinal {
        private final var foo = 1
    }

    class NoUseFinal {
        private var foo = 1
    }

    var start = Date()
    print(NoUseFinal())
    print(UseFinal())
    print("construct takes \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start))")

    start = Date()
    for _ in 1...1_000_000 {
        let temp = NoUseFinal()
    }
    print("noUseFinal took \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start))")

    start = Date()
    for _ in 1...1_000_000 {
        let temp = UseFinal()
    }
    print("useFinal took   \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start))")

    print("----")
    start = Date()
    for _ in 1...1_000_000 {
        let temp = UseFinal()
    }
    print("useFinal took   \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start))")
    start = Date()
    for _ in 1...1_000_000 {
        let temp = NoUseFinal()
    }
    print("noUseFinal took \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start))")
```

I get results as follow:

```
NoUseFinal
UseFinal
----
construct takes 0.000900983810424805
noUseFinal took 0.182932019233704
useFinal took   0.182898044586182
----
useFinal took   0.183371007442474
noUseFinal took 0.182500004768372
```

So there is no difference between `private` and `private final` methods or properties for dispatcher

Answer (score 2):

I made 2 simple classes:

```
class UseFinal
{
    private final var foo = 1
}

class NoUseFinal
{
    private var foo = 1
}
```

And ran the following code:

```
var start = Date()
for _ in 1...100000
{
    let temp = NoUseFinal()
}
print("noUseFinal took \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start))")

start = Date()
for _ in 1...100000
{
    let temp = UseFinal()
}
print("useFinal took   \(Date().timeIntervalSince(start))")
```

The results consistently showed that adding "final" clearly ran faster.  One sample output:

```
noUseFinal took 0.0214230418205261
useFinal took   0.0155709981918335
```

**EDIT**

Out of curiosity, and because of previous typo, I tried switching the order of the for loops so that the UseFinal class is hit first.  This caused THAT class to be the one that took longer: i.e. The timings were almost identical to the other run, except now the UseFinal one took longer.  This leads me to now believe that....there's no difference.  I think they boil down to the exact same bits at the end of the day.

Comment: Nice comparison. Can you (or someone else) provide any feedback on compilation times?

Answer (score 1):

`final` used for reduce dynamic dispatch at runtime.In this way the performance will be better.

> The program has to determine at runtime which method or peroperty is
>   being referred to and then perfom an indirect call or indirect access.
>   This technique, called dynamic dispatch.

`private` keyword used for visibility. When you use `private` if complier find there are no overridden declarations then complier will infer a `final` keyword in front then the all the calls become direct. Performance is improved too. But should be not as good as `final`.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily for func/vars, but if I have a file, and in that file I have a `private` class that I do not want be inheritable in that same file, I must mark that class as `final private`.